# Adding a new option to Django test management command

Tags: django

Django's test management command allows you include options like e.g.

```
python manage.py test --liveserver=localhost:8000
```

What is the recommended way to include your own new command line options, for example, if I wanted to do

```
python manage.py test --myspecialoption=True
```

or something like that?

The best way I can think of is to create a new customized test management command, e.g.

```
myproject/myapp/management/commands/mytest.py
```

and make my own new options 
there.

Is there a better or recommended way of doing this?